# Azure Deployment - How to add an assembly?

Tags: windows, azure, deployment, web-deployment, azure-web-roles

My project is working fine on localhost, but I would like to push my project on a Windows Azure Cloud Service.
I did everything nice to publish the project. However I have missing assemblies for the deployment :

```
Warning 1   The web project 'MyProject' is dependent on the following 
MVC assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\
v2.0\Assemblies\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll. MVC assemblies must be added to 
the package or installed on the virtual machine for your web role. For more details 
about this, see the following help page: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=218227.
```

I checked the references and the **Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure** is inside of the project.

[image]

Could someone could help me to add this assembly to the publish package ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you set the "Copy Local" property do True?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio since that is the most likely answer, it should be posted as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set the "Copy Local" Property to "True" on Properties Window.

[image]